# What is the way to keep track of mobile clients ip?

Tags: web-services, mobile, networking, server-side

assume Service `S` want send data to mobile App in device `A` in arbitrary time without client interaction.

what is best way to keep track of `A` IP?

the only way i can think of is to run a service for keeping track of `A` public IP (locally on `A`) if changed -> update `S` database with new IP.

It there better idea?

Comment: The client can't find its public IP without talking to a server which tells it the IP it sees.

Comment: Also what's the server supposed to do with the IP? It's not like you can simply send a message to an arbitrary client IP (NAT, firewalls, etc). It's the client that needs to establish the connection. On Android you can use GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) to send messages to a client without your app holding a connection.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this. You cannot assume that any device has a particular unique IP, or that you would be able to initiate a connection to it.

There are two problems:

### 1. NAT (Network Address Translation).

Since the IPv4 space is ridiculously constrained and IPv6 is not universally available, many networks use network address translation. That means: There's an internal network with many IP addresses and multiple devices. However, all connections are translated by a router so that they appear on the internet as sharing one IP address (that of the router).

Routers are often configured that outgoing connections are NATted automatically. As an example, imagine a LAN 192.168.0.0/24 with a client 192.168.0.7 and a router at 192.168.0.1 (local address). The router has a public address 203.0.113.111 The client wants to establish a TCP connection with a server at 203.0.113.222:80.

The client picks some random local port and initiates the connection (192.168.0.7:49152, 203.0.113.222:80). The packets are then sent to the router. The router could send the packets through unchanged, but then we would never get a response – the local address 192.168.0.7 is not routable. Instead, the router opens an outside port and pretends the packets originated there – from the outside, we see the connection (203.0.113.111:65535, 203.0.113.222:80).

When the server responds, this response is sent to the router on 203.0.113.111:65535. The router knows this port is used for NAT, and then forwards the packet to the client at 192.168.0.7:49152. After some timeout, the router stops forwarding packets on the external port.

However, routers do not generally forward incoming connections. When the router receives a connection at a port, it needs to know to which local IP+port the connection should be forwarded to. This can usually be configured manually for specific ports, e.g. “If the router receives a connection on external port 80, perform NAT to a local server on 192.168.0.2:80”.

In your case, you would want the router to forward the connections from your server to a particular device. However, there is no way to tell the router which local IP address + port you want your connection be forwarded to.

### 2. Firewalls.

The firewall of end devices or of routers sitting between you and the end device may block incoming connections unless that type of connection has been explicitly whitelisted.

### UDP is not a solution.

My above example used TCP, since the connections are easier to understand. One could also send UDP packets. While NAT for UDP packets is possible, the NAT would still have to be configured – either explicitly which doesn't help here, or implicitly if the client behind the NAT sends a packet first, and keeps sending occasional packets to keep the router from clearing that entry in the NAT table. But at that point, we effectively have a connection and might just as well use TCP.

### Push messages.

Push messages are usually implemented by keeping a client-initiated connection open for a long time. If the connection times out or if the client switches their network, the client initiates another connection. The big problem here is that keeping the connection open is energy-intensive: we need a continuous network connection, need to send keep-alive packets, and we need CPU resources to control all of that. This is not a big problem for modern PCs, but a tremendous issue for mobile devices that spend most of their time in stand-by.

The solution is to use a centralized push notification service – both Apple and Google maintain such services for their respective mobile ecosystems. Now, the mobile device doesn't need to keep open 30 connections to receive notifications from 30 services, but only one single connection. For a developer, this simplifies push messaging as well because they don't have to bother with the low-level details of these connections. Instead, push notifications are sent to a central server of the push notification provider. Instead of an IP address, you would store some more constant authorization token in your DB.